# Backup Site Data from a Bitnami Wordpress instance

Tags: backup

I have some AWS EC2 instances running with the Bitnami WordPress Multisite stack. AWS best practices recommends storing your data on a separate volume from your operating system and so I wanted to move my website's data over to a separate volume so that I can run backups on just that volume. Then, if I ever need to restore my site, I can spin up a fresh instance of the Bitnami stack, then restore and mount the volume containing the site's data.

I've looked through the files on the server and have found that Bitnami has the database, wp-config.php and wp-content all within a single directory. What I want to know is whether backing up just those files is sufficient to completely restore my site to a fresh instance or does WordPress store website / user data in other places that I should also be backing up.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami support got back to my support ticket with the following response:

> Yes, the data that requires persistence can be found in the "/bitnami" folder. Specifically, the "/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php" file and the "/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content" directory are symbolically linked to the "/bitnami/wordpress" folder. Similarly, the MariaDB data is symbolically linked to "/bitnami/mariadb". However, it's important to note that this solution is not tested for VMs and may lead to issues, (especially with major version changes) for example when a newer version of WordPress expects a database table to be present, which doesn't exist in the old version, etc.